# How to clear cookies, history and other private data in the Chrome browser?

Tags: privacy, cache, delete

Is there any way to delete cookies, history and other private data in the Google Chrome browser on Android? There is no such option in the Android version of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear all browsing data from Settings -> Privacy -> Clear browsing data.

Source : [Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?hl=en)